# intern grunt unable to load packages which are siblings of the package being tested

Tags: testing, dojo, intern

I'm having a problem loading tests in a package who's dependencies are siblings of the package being tested.

The currently messy code committed is at https://github.com/lbod/delite/tree/intern-bforbes-setup.
The sibling dependencies of this package are dojo and dcl, therefore I used the loader intern config to set the baseUrl to '..' i.e.

```
loader: {
    baseUrl: '..',
    packages: [
        'delite',
        'dojo',
        'dcl'
    ]
}
```

When loading the grunt test:local task, the tests-intern/intern.local intern config will load via grunt but the client.html unit test will not resolve intern.local

```
GET http://localhost:9000/tests-intern/intern.local.js 404 (Not Found) dojo.js:725
Uncaught Error: Failed to load module tests-intern/intern.local from /tests-intern/intern.local.js (parent: *2)
```

However if I change the URL of client html (I'm able to do this because the test err'd and didn't close the browser) to `http://localhost:9000/__intern/client.html?baseUrl=%2F&config=delite/tests-intern%2Fintern.local&reporters=webdriver&sessionId=48ba4743-2475-478c-b7a2-d94d661782ae`, tests will run successfully

It feels like a catch 22 because if I change the intern Grunt task config to `config: 'delite/tests-intern/intern.local'` the task won't load intern.local.js

Is this possible and if so how?

Answer (score 1):

So for anyone else that finds this issue, it was marked as a bug in intern https://github.com/theintern/intern/issues/139 and am awaiting a tagged release